# Display column based on the displayed row from another SQL Server table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

How to display the row data value as column name in VB.NET?

Given some of the table structure.

Table 1 with its original columns and sample data:

```
RECEIPTNO    PIZZA   NOODLES  BURGER   BEVERAGES
--------------------------------------------------
  100          35      0        12          5
```

Table 2 with only 2 rows of data in it:

```
FOODNAME  FOODTYPE
------------------
NOODLES    ASIAN FOOD
BEVERAGES  BEVERAGES
```

Expected Table 1 to be shown with every row with food name at table 2.

```
RECEIPTNO  NOODLES  BEVERAGES
------------------------------
   100       0          5
```

Comment: Table 2 clearly has 2 rows of data.

Comment: I mean, row value to become header name for another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I download from Table2 to get the columns you want from Table1. Looping through the result builds the SELECT statement.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT FOODNAME FROM Table2;", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            cn.Close()
        End Using

        Dim sqlSelect = "SELECT RECEIPTNO"
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            sqlSelect &= "," & row("FOODNAME").ToString
        Next
        sqlSelect &= " FROM Table1;"
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlSelect, cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt2.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt2
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems ok. Can the columns name to be separated by its behavior? Like in the new table 1, I would like to have RECEIPTNO,NOODLES1,NOODLES2,...?

Comment: NOODLES1 and NOODLES2 would have to be present in Table2 and be valid columns in Table1

Comment: How about I want to make column which end with "1" to be green? Like noodles1,beverage1 as green